# what is the Difference between using mysql connector and Flask-Mysql in Flask app?

Tags: flask, mysql-connector-python, flask-mysql

I am new to Flask app development, i need some clarifications on using database with flask app. 
We have a MySQL db which has some metrics, currently we generate some reports using python using MySQL.connector.
We have python modules/functions to fetch the data from the db using mysql.connector and populate a dictionary which has data to be put in the report. 
My question is can i use the same python module in the app.py (if this is where i create the app) and get the data as dictionary and pass it to some template html to render the report?
If i can do this, what is the advantage of using Flask-MySql or Flask-SqlAlchemy and doing the app.config[] things which are mentioned in many tutorials?

I am trying to understand what should be used when.

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy is the Flask extension for the ORM SQLAlchemy. As an ORM SQLAlchemy provides support for multiple databases (you can check its full features [here](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/features.html)). As far as I understand, you are not creating a full fledged web application on flask which would require multiple connections to the db so I think Flask-SQLAlchemy would be overkill. You wouldn't be using many of the features it provides. I'd go with Flask-MySQL for your usecase

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your case, if you don't have much experience in SQL, I recommend using an ORM like SQLAlchemy. For Flask, there is an extension called Flask-SQLAlchemy that uses Python-like syntax without using direct SQL. It's easy to learn and well-documented, but not recommended for advanced user cases. If you need to pass pure SQL queries through Flask and require more capabilities in the database, it's better to use a Flask extension for MySQL, like Flask-MySQL. It depends on your requirements, capabilities, and use case.